# D3 force simulation graph, edges fail to render for larger datasets

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

**EDIT: For those interested in efficiency with large datasets the accepted answer is useful and I've needed to implement it anyhow. But the more direct cause of the problem as pointed in comments was that the db wasn't sending all the edges for large queries. So this was an X Y problem.**

I am using d3.forceSimulation to create a network graph in the browser. The graph works as intended for a low number of edges (see fig 1.) For a large number of edges (approc > 500), most of the edges start failing to render (see fig 2.) This is of course the undesired behaviour.

So far I have tried increasing the size of the canvas, and also adjusting the update to only run on every 20th tick. There has been no improvement in edge rendering from either of these changes.

I am willing to sacrifice performance if required (eg, lower framerate). It is important that I am able to display at least 1000 nodes on the graph. I do not know what parameters I could change to achieve this as I'm not sure what exactly is causing the problem.

The simulation setup code is copied in below. I have also included the drawEdge function below, since I used a very manual process to make the graph directed (draw triangles), and in particular the arctan function has given me issues in the past. So perhaps there is a problem there.
4
Thank you.

Simulation setup:

```
   simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force("x", d3.forceX(canvasWidth/2))
        .force("y", d3.forceY(canvasHeight/2))
        .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(nodeRadius+1))
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody()
                .strength(-90))
        .force("link", d3.forceLink()
                .id(function (d) { return d.id; }))
        .on("tick", queue_update);

    simulation.nodes(graph.nodes);
    simulation.force("link")
        .links(graph.edges);
```

drawLink function:

```
function drawLink(l) {
    //Setup for line
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle=colors[l.source.court];

    //Draw a line between the nodes
    ctx.moveTo(l.source.x, l.source.y);
    ctx.lineTo(l.target.x, l.target.y);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";

    //Setup for arrow
    var line_angle = Math.atan2(l.source.y - l.target.y, l.source.x - l.target.x);
    var x_move = Math.cos(line_angle);
    var y_move = Math.sin(line_angle);
    var on_line_x = l.target.x + x_move*11;
    var on_line_y = l.target.y + y_move*11;

    var on_line_x_2 = l.target.x + x_move*6;
    var on_line_y_2 = l.target.y + y_move*6;


    ctx.moveTo(on_line_x, on_line_y);
    ctx.lineTo(on_line_x - y_move, on_line_y + x_move);
    ctx.lineTo(on_line_x_2, on_line_y_2);
    ctx.lineTo(on_line_x + y_move, on_line_y - x_move);
    ctx.lineTo(on_line_x, on_line_y);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

[image: Figure 1: Desired Behaviour]

[image: Figure 2: Actual Behaviour with large datasets]

Edit: Minimal example can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19efUYOaB6D04jVg4FfjxEQbw8Mcwa1pm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There might be more than rendering issues here - try to comment `charge` and `collide` functions and see if something improves. There might be a need to implement a more performant custom layout function

Comment: Okay thank you I will try that now.

Comment: Try setting up a [mcve] demonstrating the issue. Strip it down to the bare minimum getting rid of all the fancy colors, varying radii, markers, labels,... leave it to just enough to reproduce your problem. That would make it much easier for others to help you out.

Comment: @CornelStefanache commenting out charge and collide does appear to solve the edge problem. Do you have any pointers for how to implement a more performant custom layout function.

Comment: @altocumulus let me see what I can do. It's difficult to provide a reproducible example because I'd have to give you the data as well, which is big.

Comment: What is the basic data structure? We can generate synthetic data to work with, it is a graph or a tree, are isolated clusters present, what are ranges for different properties?

Comment: Graph data structure. List of nodes and edges. No isolated clusters: the node with a black circle around it is the center and all other nodes are related to that (in the second example up to a depth of three). Let me see whether I can create a minimal example. Might take a while.

Comment: @CornelStefanache Okay, Stackoverflow has a character limit. I'd prefer to avoid you the hassle of generating data. So here is a public Google Drive link to an html file with a minimal example with enough data to break things: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19efUYOaB6D04jVg4FfjxEQbw8Mcwa1pm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Neil Well, you have 185 nodes which are not connected... What do you expect? There will be no links for those, am I right? Check the console output of this demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/oyUykVXsecDilF9FX8jA?p=preview.

Comment: @Neil I worked a little bit on the rendering operations - see my answer below - hope it helps - did some performance and there is some improvment

Comment: Thank you both. @altocumulus okay perhaps I have more than 1 problem! The answer from Cornel has helped already. I'll do some logging on the backend to see if I'm losing data. Will update when it's all working correctly.

Comment: @Neil This modified version of the demo colors all non-connected nodes red which clearly shows your problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/AKo6NVqMAyPuEaLUlUoc?p=preview

Comment: Thank you altocumulus. I have found the reason for the lost links now as well (the graphdb was limiting its response).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to optimise rendering functions (nodes and links) as such: render only if they are visible in the viewport and let D3 do the charge / collide calculations on all nodes

First you will have to define the width/height of the viewport and the representative rectangle:

```
const WIDTH = 600;
const HEIGHT = 600;
const viewport = {left: 0, top: 0, right: WIDTH, bottom: HEIGHT}
```

The most basic thing to do to check if a link crosses the viewport is to check if the rectangle defined by the source and target intersects with the viewport:

```
function intersectRect(r1, r2) {
  return !(r2.left > r1.right || 
           r2.right < r1.left || 
           r2.top > r1.bottom ||
           r2.bottom < r1.top);
}

function drawLink(l) {

    const lineRect = {
      left: Math.min(l.source.x, l.target.x),
      right: Math.max(l.source.x, l.target.x),
      top: Math.min(l.source.y, l.target.y),
      bottom: Math.max(l.source.y, l.target.y),
    }

    // draw only if they intersect         
    if (intersectRect(lineRect, viewport)) {

      //Setup for line
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";

      //Draw a line between the nodes
      ctx.moveTo(l.source.x, l.source.y);
      ctx.lineTo(l.target.x, l.target.y);
      ctx.stroke();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";

      //Setup for arrow
      var line_angle = Math.atan2(l.source.y - l.target.y, l.source.x - l.target.x);
      var x_move = Math.cos(line_angle);
      var y_move = Math.sin(line_angle);
      var on_line_x = l.target.x + x_move*11;
      var on_line_y = l.target.y + y_move*11;

      var on_line_x_2 = l.target.x + x_move*6;
      var on_line_y_2 = l.target.y + y_move*6;

      ctx.moveTo(on_line_x, on_line_y);
      ctx.lineTo(on_line_x - y_move, on_line_y + x_move);
      ctx.lineTo(on_line_x_2, on_line_y_2);
      ctx.lineTo(on_line_x + y_move, on_line_y - x_move);
      ctx.lineTo(on_line_x, on_line_y);
      ctx.stroke();
   }
}
```

the same thing can be done for nodes when rendering

```
function drawNode(d) {
    if (d.x > 0 && d.x< WIDTH && d.y> 0 && d.y< HEIGHT){ 
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.fillStyle = "#666";
       fill_node(d)
    }
}

function fill_node(d) {
    if (d.x > 0 && d.x < WIDTH && d.y > 0 && d.y < HEIGHT){ 
      ctx.moveTo(d.x, d.y);
      ctx.arc(d.x, d.y, nodeRadius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
      ctx.fill();
    }
}
```